# Simple transfer of currently logged in user to save. Django

Tags: django, forms

I am looking for the simplest way to transfer the currently logged in user to my model.

My model looks like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

My **forms.py**

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('name', )
```

My **views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PersonForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.user = request.user.username
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:home'))
else:
    form = PersonForm()
```

Why is not my user save method working? how is it easiest to save it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work without the `username` part. Also you need to use **[form.save(commit=False)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)** to generate a `Person` model instance(which has not been saved to DB yet), like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PersonForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        person = form.save(commit=False)
        person.user = request.user
        person.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:home'))
else:
    form = PersonForm()
```